# How can I ignore/hide constraints warnings in storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I want to know how to ignore/hide the warning about constraints in storyboard, so that I don't see the warnings in storyboard. Programmatically I set the right constraints.

Many thanks to You

[image]

Comment: Just look away and move on?

Comment: @matt yeah that would work but I want an elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply workable constraints in the storyboard and update them programmatically. You can attach constraints to IBOutlets if you want to directly modify the existing ones (this is how I do most programmatic constraints). There is no way to turn off storyboard warnings.

Comment: What I don't understand: for some UIButtons the storyboard give me constraints warnings and for other UIButtons the storyboard doesn't. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Add constraints in Storyboard, then select them all and drag to your ViewController to create a collection:

[image]

In your code, deactivate them:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var storyboardConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        storyboardConstraints.forEach { $0.isActive = false }

        self.view.addConstraints([
            self.label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

I must admit, it's not a great solution.